# Notion of a projection

Tags: functions

I'm trying to understand the notion of a projection. The textbook I'm using (Aluffi: Chapter Zero) gives a few examples, but not a clear definition. For example, the map $\pi_A: A \times B \to A$ sending $(a,b) \longmapsto a$ is a projection. After some more searching, a definition I found (from Wikipedia) is:

> In mathematics, a projection is a mapping of a set (or other mathematical structure) into a subset (or sub-structure), which is equal to its square for mapping composition (or, in other words, which is idempotent).

But this definition doesn't make any sense. I can't compose $\pi_A$ with itself: that wouldn't even be well-defined. Similarly, the map from $A \to A/\sim$ sending $a \to [a]$, another given example of a projection, can't be composed with itself. The domain/codomain don't align.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot compose any projection with itself, only when the codomain is a subset of the domain, for example, the projection $ (a,b) \to a $ from $ \mathbb{R^2} $ to $ \mathbb{R} $ , cannot be composed with itself.

Comment: This makes sense, but what then would be the definition of a projection map if not idempotence?

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases, you can regard the projection as a map $$\pi_A : A\times B\to A\times \{b\}$$ for some fixed $b\in B$. Then $\pi_A\circ\pi_A$ makes sense. Admittedly, this is rather sloppy, but it communicates the idea of "projection" in a literal sense.

Similarly for projection onto the other coordinate(s).